# how to find the created textbox on a dynamic gridview in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Hi I'm about to update some data through a textbox created on a dynamic filled Gridview but sadly when I click the update button, my code cannot read what I have inputed on those textboxes. Heres my code:

```
sqlcon = New SqlConnection(conString)

        Dim id = GridAnswers.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim row As GridViewRow = TryCast(GridAnswers.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)
        Dim ChoiceDescription As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("ChoiceDescription"), TextBox)
        Dim Rating As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("Rating"), TextBox)
        DropDownList)
        Using sqlcon As New SqlConnection
        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE CS_RefQuestionChoice SET ChoiceDescription=@choice, RatingID=@ratingid WHERE ChoiceID=@qid"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choice", ChoiceDescription.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ratingid", Rating.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            sqlcon.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcon.Close()
        End Using
         End Using
        GridAnswers.EditIndex = -1
        gridbind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to bind the gridview only if the page is not posted back.